# Odoo Add Tax on invoice by Code but Total on Invoice not change

Tags: odoo

I am  trying to add tax into invoice line by doing

```
discount_l.write({'tax_ids': tax_ids})
```

which did add tax into 'account_move_line' but the total of invoice did not change. I try debug and notice that onchange method did not trigger. I read some document and onchange only triggers on FORM. What should I do? I dont know how many onchange methods I need to call manually

Comment: Try to call `_recompute_dynamic_lines` on the invoice, maybe it will work

Answer (score 0):

The total will be automatically computed if you update the invoice lines using the invoice reference.

In the following example, we will use the new commands [link](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/15.0/developer/reference/backend/orm.html#odoo.fields.Command) function to update a specific invoice line `tax_ids` field:

***Example:***

```
invoice_id.write({'invoice_line_ids': [Command.update(invoice_line_id, {'tax_ids': tax_ids})]})
```